# Moment js Is there a way to set a time that will be the same for all timezones?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

For example, I want to set a variable to 4 pm, where it will be 4 pm for everyone. I'm sure there will be some sort of solution for that, a real-world example is, you set a calendar event for 4 pm, and whoever is in that event will also receive the reminder at 4 pm of their timezones, how do we achieve it?

I've been googling and looking at the moment js docs but I couldn't figure it out yet, any thoughts?

I've been working on this jsFiddle but I don't think this is the path, https://jsfiddle.net/wmoreiradev/y70Lnmzb/7/

```
const utcOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
const date = moment('2020-06-24T23:45:00.000Z').utcOffset(utcOffset).toDate();
```

Comment: I think you might be looking or the `utc()` method: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is ambiguous, as 4 PM in all timezone is just simply doesn't exist at the same time.

BUT, for any reason, if you want to do it, you can do it, just pass the date as a simple string out it in the simple string. From simple string, I mean not a date object.

```
moment("4:00PM", "hh:mmA").format();
```

It will always give you `4:00PM` in all the timezone.

[image]